# How i can include a parameter for indexing in a comprehension list in python?

Tags: python

Suppose i have a dictionary `dic` and a list `keylist` containing some keys of my dictionary. I would like to create a comprehension list containing all the values of the `dic` with keys from the `keylist`.

I have a code like this:

```
 [x for x in dic[keylist[i]] for i in range(len(keylist))]
```

but i am getting this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Comment: `range(len(keylist))` almost always can be reworked to just use `keylist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want:

```
 [dic[x] for x in keylist]
```

To iterate over a list, you don't need to use index but just `for element in alist`. Not to raise a `KeyError`, you can use:

`[dic[x] for x in keylist if x in dic]` or `[dic.get(x) for x in keylist]`

Comment: Well, actually yes. Seemingly I did not even read the code - OP's code is just obfuscated version of you are really trying to do.

Comment: Also, if you've got keys in `keylist` that are not in `dic` you'll get a KeyError and you could do `[dic[x] for x in keylist if x in dic]` instead.

Comment: Yes. Also can use `dic.get(x)`.@SamStudio8

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
[x for i in range(len(keylist)) for x in dic[keylist[i]]]
```

The order is just different.

But this is really rather obfuscated version of what you should write instead. The better option is in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17630209/548696).